# Duration range video player in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using `video_player` package to show my video, and now want set starting and finishing positions for my video, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**seekTo** is what you are looking for:

`_controller.seekTo(Duration(seconds: 10));`

From the source code:

```
  /// Sets the video's current timestamp to be at [moment]. The next
  /// time the video is played it will resume from the given [moment].
  ///
  /// If [moment] is outside of the video's full range it will be automatically
  /// and silently clamped.
  Future<void> seekTo(Duration position) async {
    if (_isDisposed) {
      return;
    }
    if (position > value.duration) {
      position = value.duration;
    } else if (position < const Duration()) {
      position = const Duration();
    }
    await _videoPlayerPlatform.seekTo(_textureId, position);
    _updatePosition(position);
  }
```

And if you what to stop it after stop time just use *Future.delayed*:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
  setState(() {
    _controller.pause();
  });
});
```

Comment: ``seekTo()`` set starting position for video, but I want set starting and ending positions

Comment: Are you downloading the video or is it part of the app ? You want to download only a portion of it or really just load a portion of it ?

Comment: No, not about download, for example, I have video with 15 seconds duration and I want  play only video from 3 seconds to 7 seconds.

Comment: Well with what I gave you you can achieve what you want don't you? If you want to load only part of an asset I don't think it's possible looking at AssetBundle. Another solution would be to use flutter_ffmpeg, thus creating a new shorter video, and then loading the video. Depends on your needs really.

Comment: This doesn't solve the usecase described. What if the user pauses the video?

Comment: Actually it depends, @esfsef did not specify that the user could control the video. If that's the case for sure you have to handle the pause, jumping etc. But if you simply want to play the video while the user has no control on it this works just fine

Comment: @syonip sorry I did not tag you so you might not have been notified. See my response above.